# To Hook Web Content Search Portlet

Tags: java, search, liferay, hook

How will I customize the searching of the **Web Content Search Portlet** ?

I've tried to add the following in portal-ext.properties but it seemed not working. The result is always "No pages were found that matched the keywords: a".

```
com.liferay.portlet.blogs.util.BlogsOpenSearchImpl=true
com.liferay.portlet.bookmarks.util.BookmarksOpenSearchImpl=true
com.liferay.portlet.calendar.util.CalendarOpenSearchImpl=true
com.liferay.portlet.directory.util.DirectoryOpenSearchImpl=true
com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.util.DLOpenSearchImpl=true
com.liferay.portlet.imagegallery.util.IGOpenSearchImpl=true
com.liferay.portlet.journal.util.JournalOpenSearchImpl=true
com.liferay.portlet.messageboards.util.MBOpenSearchImpl=true
com.liferay.portlet.wiki.util.WikiOpenSearchImpl=true
```

It only searching in the Web content files and journal article. I don't know what to do. Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Web Content Search** portlet only searches web content articles.
They have to be type JournalArticle to be searched.

You may try with **Search** portlet.

Comment: Yep. I used Search portlet and I just customized the **start.jsp** that can be found at _liferay-developer-studio\liferay-portal-6.2-ee-sp8\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT\html\taglib\ui\search\start.jsp_

Answer (score 1):

Please try reindexing the Search Indexes from the server settings in the control panel of Liferay. If this does not help, try to crank up the logging levels in the control panel. Set:
com.liferay.portal.search.lucene.LuceneIndexSearcherImpl to debug or even higher if you like. Take a look at the Server output and check if something funny is going on there. But my first guess would be a corrupt search index.